How to typeset Dijkstra choice with TeX Gyre Termes and STIX Two Math? Other font suggestions are welcome
Continuing How to draw the box of Dijkstra's Guarded Command Language?, let's try to retypeset EWD's programs.  Let's test STIX Math, with ⫾ (Dijkstra choice, U+2AFE), the same symbol in \displaystyle, ⫿ (n-ary Dijkstra choice, U+2AFF), and the same symbol in \displaystyle:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont[Extension=.otf,range={"2AFE,"2AFF}]{STIXMath-Regular}% outdated font with issues
\setmathfont[range={}]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\newcommand{\keyword}[1]{\textsf{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\mdoloop}{\keyword{do}}
\newcommand{\modloop}{\keyword{od}}
\newcommand{\mthen}{\keyword{\textrightarrow}}
\newcommand{\mif}{\keyword{if}}
\newcommand{\mfi}{\keyword{fi}}
\setlength{\tabbingsep}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  {\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
    \begin{tabbing}
      q1, q2, q3, q4 \(≔\) Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4;\\
      \mdoloop\=\ \=q1 \textgreater\ q2 \=\kill
      \mdoloop\>\>q1 \textgreater\ q2\>\mthen\ q1, q2 \(≔\) q2, q1\\
      \>#1\'\>q2 \textgreater\ q3\>\mthen\ q2, q3 \(≔\) q3, q2\\
      \>#1\'\>q3 \textgreater\ q4\>\mthen\ q3, q4 \(≔\) q4, q3\\
      \modloop;\\
      k \(≔\) 0; j \(≔\) 1;\\
      \mdoloop\ j \(\neq\) n \mthen\ \=\mif\=\ \=f(j) \(\le\) f(k)\ \=\kill
      \mdoloop\ j \(\neq\) n \mthen\ \>\mif\>\ \>f(j) \(\le\) f(k)\ \>\mthen\ j \(≔\) j + 1\\
      \>\>#1\'\>f(j) \(\ge\) f(k)\ \>\mthen\ k \(≔\) j; j \(≔\) j + 1\\
      \>\mfi\\
      \modloop\qquad.
  \end{tabbing}}%
}%
\noindent
Dijkstra choice:
\test{\(⫾\)}
\noindent
Dijkstra choice in display style:
\test{\(\displaystyle ⫾\)}
\noindent
n-ary Dijkstra choice:
\test{\(⫿\)}
\noindent
n-ary Dijkstra choice in display style:
\test{\(\displaystyle ⫿\)}
\end{document}

Running lualatex yields

The first three choices above are good enough for me.
As STIX Math is old and has other, unrelated issues (cf. In TeX Live 2024, why does \substack insert a vertical gap between the lines when STIXMath-Regular is loaded?), we try to transition to STIX Two Math:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont[Extension=.otf,range={"2AFE,"2AFF}]{STIXTwoMath-Regular}% more modern
\setmathfont[range={}]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\newcommand{\keyword}[1]{\textsf{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\mdoloop}{\keyword{do}}
\newcommand{\modloop}{\keyword{od}}
\newcommand{\mthen}{\keyword{\textrightarrow}}
\newcommand{\mif}{\keyword{if}}
\newcommand{\mfi}{\keyword{fi}}
\setlength{\tabbingsep}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  {\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
    \begin{tabbing}
      q1, q2, q3, q4 \(≔\) Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4;\\
      \mdoloop\=\ \=q1 \textgreater\ q2 \=\kill
      \mdoloop\>\>q1 \textgreater\ q2\>\mthen\ q1, q2 \(≔\) q2, q1\\
      \>#1\'\>q2 \textgreater\ q3\>\mthen\ q2, q3 \(≔\) q3, q2\\
      \>#1\'\>q3 \textgreater\ q4\>\mthen\ q3, q4 \(≔\) q4, q3\\
      \modloop;\\
      k \(≔\) 0; j \(≔\) 1;\\
      \mdoloop\ j \(\neq\) n \mthen\ \=\mif\=\ \=f(j) \(\le\) f(k)\ \=\kill
      \mdoloop\ j \(\neq\) n \mthen\ \>\mif\>\ \>f(j) \(\le\) f(k)\ \>\mthen\ j \(≔\) j + 1\\
      \>\>#1\'\>f(j) \(\ge\) f(k)\ \>\mthen\ k \(≔\) j; j \(≔\) j + 1\\
      \>\mfi\\
      \modloop\qquad.
  \end{tabbing}}%
}%
\noindent
Dijkstra choice:
\test{\(⫾\)}
\noindent
Dijkstra choice in display style:
\test{\(\displaystyle ⫾\)}
\noindent
n-ary Dijkstra choice:
\test{\(⫿\)}
\noindent
n-ary Dijkstra choice in display style:
\test{\(\displaystyle ⫿\)}
\end{document}

Running lualatex on it yields

As you see, the symbol ⫾ (Dijkstra choice, U+2AFE) is now shorter and stays on the baseline, whereas in Dijkstra's https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/ewd04xx/EWD472.PDF, the choice symbol descends also below the baseline:

Note that in Dijkstra's work, the symbol is not only deeper but also taller than the small letters such as x. In terms of the bounding rectangle, the might be roughly comparable to a math-mode paren ( or ), as all these symbols start lower below the baseline and finish above the x-height.
So the symbol ⫾ (Dijkstra choice, U+2AFE) has got worse in my opinion from STIX two STIX Two. Any rationale why it happened? Is this intentional or a bug?
The only visibly usable STIX2-symbol in this context is now ⫿ (n-ary Dijkstra choice, U+2AFF) in its inline version, which contradicts its intended usage as a big symbol. Again, any rationale why it happened? Is this intentional or a bug?
Moreover, for both fonts, the symbol isn't exactly right-aligned in the column with the keywords denoting the statement to which the choice belongs, i.e., do…od or if…fi. The symbol could be moved to the right a little bit. Any idea why the symbol is not precisely right-aligned? Is this intentional or a bug? How to make the symbol precisely right-aligned?
Overall, what to do? How to typeset Dijkstra choice with TeX Gyre Termes and STIX Two Math properly (if possible)? Other suggestions for a free and not outdated font to take the Dijkstra choice U+2AFE from that would jive with TeX Gyre Termes Math?

I vote to close this as opinion based. The question why a font designer decided to give a glyph a certain look or size is not on topic here.

Concerning your “the question why …”: While certainly I'm also interested in “why”, the main question, namely, in the title, “How to typeset Dijkstra choice with TeX Gyre Termes and STIX Two Math?”, starts with “how”, and NOT with “why”. There is also a “what” subquestion inside.

There may be a "what" question somewhere in there, but I personally get a bit bored paging through exposition.  If the question is how to typeset an individual glyph, can't you trim the code down to 10 lines, and the output to 2?

Your question still contains aspects which are opinion based and only answerable by most likely a single font designer. 90% of your question is just unanswerable. About the right alignment: That's something one could ask here, but (without taking a real look at the font/glyphs) I'd guess this is because the bounding box is bigger to the right than the visual glyph, again something only the font designer can answer why that's the case. The remedy would be a manual kern.

Btw, New Computer Modern has a longer Dijkstra symbol, like the one in XITS/Stix. Just for reference if anyone is looking for a CM compatible version.

@ApoorvPotnis Thx!

Only moderators and the site have the ability to delete comments, not Skillmon. See "What happens when I flag a comment?" in https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts.  So it seems like multiple people feel your comments are out of line.

The question is rather too long and unspecific, and not unreasonably got closed as opinion-based, but I asked for it to be re-opened as I think there is a TeX question (or at least a TeX font question) that can be answered.
Firstly the positioning of the symbol on the baseline rather than below, while it changed between stix1 and stix2, isn't unique to that font. In particular Cambria math, which is effectively the reference OpenType Math font, has the symbol on the baseline, as does (I think, it's not terribly clear) the reference character chart at unicode.org

Secondly your comment

The only visibly usable STIX2-symbol in this context is now ⫿ (n-ary Dijkstra choice, U+2AFF) in its inline version, which contradicts its intended usage as a big symbol.

seems to be a misunderstanding, as far as I can see all the uses shown both inline and display are as a prefix operator so \mathop is the right math class. unicode-math sets up the smaller U+2AFE as a \mathbin for infix binary spacing, so if used as a prefix at the start of the list it gets no spacing at all just as - loses its space if used as -2  so with the default setup U+2AFE (\bigtalloblong) is the correct character here. so the relation is like \union and \bigunion
However if you want the smaller character you can force it to have \mathop spacing as below.
The following page shows the fonts are not entirely consistent (and most available opentype math fonts don't have these characters at all) but having the smaller version on the baseline is perhaps most common, especially in more recent fonts.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\DeclareMathVersion{Stix2}
\setmathfont[version=Stix2]{STIX Two Math}
\DeclareMathVersion{XITS}
\setmathfont[version=XITS]{XITSMath-Regular.otf}
\DeclareMathVersion{Cambria}
\setmathfont[version=Cambria]{Cambria Math}
\DeclareMathVersion{NotoSans}
\setmathfont[version=NotoSans]{NotoSansMath-Regular.otf}
\DeclareMathVersion{NCM}
\setmathfont[version=NCM]{NewCMMath-Book.otf}
\DeclareMathVersion{GFSHellenic}
\setmathfont[version=GFSHellenic]{GFSNeohellenicMath}

\NewDocumentCommand\test{m}{{%
\subsubsection*{#1}
\mathversion{#1}
\parbox[t]{.33\textwidth}{\textbf{binop U+2AFE}\\
I: $ \talloblong q_1 > q_2 $
D: $\displaystyle \talloblong q_1 > q_2 $
}%
\parbox[t]{.33\textwidth}{\textbf{mathop U+2AFE}\\
I: $ \mathop{\talloblong} q_1 > q_2 $
D: $\displaystyle \mathop{\talloblong} q_1 > q_2 $
}%
\parbox[t]{.33\textwidth}{\textbf{mathop U+2AFF}\\
I: $ \bigtalloblong q_1 > q_2 $
D: $\displaystyle \bigtalloblong q_1 > q_2 $
}%
\par
}}

\begin{document}

\test{Stix2}
\test{XITS}
\test{Cambria}
\test{NotoSans}
\test{NCM}
\test{GFSHellenic}


\end{document}

If however you choose a font such as Stix2 with the smller version on the baseline but do want to use it lowered, that is not so hard to do, but using U+2AFF seems simpler.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,unicode-math}

\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\NewDocumentCommand\test{m}{{%
\subsubsection*{#1}
\mathversion{#1}
\parbox[t]{.33\textwidth}{\textbf{binop U+2AFE}\\
I: $ \talloblong q_1 > q_2 $
D: $\displaystyle \talloblong q_1 > q_2 $
}%
\parbox[t]{.33\textwidth}{\textbf{mathop U+2AFE}\\
I: $ \mathop{\talloblong} q_1 > q_2 $
D: $\displaystyle \mathop{\talloblong} q_1 > q_2 $
}%
\parbox[t]{.33\textwidth}{\textbf{mathop U+2AFF}\\
I: $ \bigtalloblong q_1 > q_2 $
D: $\displaystyle \bigtalloblong q_1 > q_2 $
}%
\par
}}

\NewDocumentCommand\dchoice{}{%
  \mathop{\mathchoice
    {\raisebox{-.25em}{\scalebox{1.1}[1.5]{$\talloblong$}}}%
    {\raisebox{-.2em}{$\talloblong$}}%
    {\talloblong}%
    {\talloblong}%
  }%
  }

\begin{document}

\subsection*{mathop U+2AFE}
I: $ \mathop{\talloblong} q_1 > q_2 $
D: $\displaystyle \mathop{\talloblong} q_1 > q_2 $


\subsection*{mathop U+2AFE lowered}
I: $ \dchoice q_1 > q_2 $
D: $\displaystyle \dchoice q_1 > q_2 $


\subsection*{mathop U+2AFF}
I: $ \bigtalloblong q_1 > q_2 $
D: $\displaystyle \bigtalloblong q_1 > q_2 $

\end{document}



I updated the question with a screenshot of Dijkstra's original. U+2AFE is better than U+2AFF because then this symbol also appears in the text layer of a generated PDF file, which simplifies the search. So vertically scaling the rectangle and lowering it below the baseline might be the way to go. It helps! Thank you!

As for \mathbin vs \mathop, I hope they don't play any role in my examples because I typeset programs only inside tabbing, where the symbol is alone in its cell, hopefully properly right-aligned. Any take on why the symbol is not exactly right-aligned?

@AlMa1r but I think my main point here is that Dijkstra's original isn't the reference that a font designer would or should use, while the unicode character chart does mention Dijkstra in a note, "Dijkstra choice" isn't the primary name of the codepoint it's  WHITE VERTICAL BAR and N-ARY WHITE VERTICAL BAR  and the primary description of the visual character is the code chart. for the prefix form I'd say 2AFF is arguably more correct so I can't agree with your comment that U+2AFE  simplifies search, that's only true if you are searching for the wrong symbol.

Then the correspondence between the white vertical bar and Dijkstras choice is partially flawed. When you do a text search for EWD's original program, you'd search for, say, ⫾ q2 > q3 and ⫾ f(j) ≥ f(k) with U+2AFE because mathematically, it's a binary operator (only in EWD's formatting, this operator always starts a line).

well yes but using tabbing and moving in and out of math mode for each symbol (which isn't needed for luatex you could just use the symbols in text) means you are losing all tex's math layout rules anyway so worrying too much about the fine placement seems mis placed.  Also why just the box symbol that you ask about, compared to the typewritter original lots of characters vary eg the \leq symbol is clearly much further below the baseline in the original than in the typeset version you show, it happens.

@AlMa1r shrug, text search is only possible in such a small number of cases without tagging with some alternative form such as latex or mathml source,  you have used tabbing and almost all text mode with ascii characters so close to the typewitter form which is Ok in your use case being faithful to the original but in any more normal use such as the versions I used where the math is in math mode, even a simple search for q1 will fail as the q is U+1D45E `` so searching for an ascii q (as appeared in the tex source) will fail in most search engines

As for the math mode, I minimize its usage in this example because specifically here, I view programs as concrete textual objects rather than mathematical formulas. (Specifically here, we're not talking about other usages.) If we had text-mode less-than-or-equal-to, I'd use that. And no, with lualatex, if we use ⫾ instead of \(⫾\), the symbol doesn't show up in the PDF output.

Btw., searching for ⫾ q2 > q3 in evince succeeds in my output whenever the symbol is actually displayed.

@AlMa1r you have to use a font that has the symbol but you don't have to use math mode.  you could not use unicode-math  and just use \newfontfamily\stix{STIX Two Math}  then, in text, use {\stix ⫾}

@AlMa1r yes because for this document you have simple  text and no math layout so the search can work, but as I say in any more normal math typesetting setting it will work less often

Thx for \newfontfamily\stix{STIX Two Math} and then {\stix ⫾}! I completely forgot about that. In fact, I use STIX Two Math also for other, proper mathematical symbols, such as ⁀. Can I do both, i.e., use STIX Two Math both as text font for a small subset of symbols and as a math font for another, distinct subset of symbols?

@AlMa1r Sure, you can even use it for the same symbols both as text font and as math font. Just load it once though unicode-math and once through \newfontfamily, then you get for all intents and purposes separate fonts which just happen to look rather similar.

This answer focuses on the following part of the question:

Moreover, for both fonts, the symbol isn't exactly right-aligned in the column with the keywords denoting the statement to which the choice belongs, i.e., do…od or if…fi. The symbol could be moved to the right a little bit. Any idea why the symbol is not precisely right-aligned? Is this intentional or a bug? How to make the symbol precisely right-aligned?

The reason for this is the bounding box of the symbol which is noticeably wider than the glyph. We can make this visible with a small auxiliary \bb which draws a tight red box around its argument. Whether that larger bounding box is intentional or a bug I can't answer.
In the output of the following we can see that the bounding boxes are indeed right-aligned:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont[Extension=.otf,range={"2AFE,"2AFF}]{STIXTwoMath-Regular}% more modern
\setmathfont[range={}]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\newcommand{\keyword}[1]{\textsf{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\mdoloop}{\bb{\keyword{do}}}
\newcommand{\modloop}{\bb{\keyword{od}}}
\newcommand{\mif}{\bb{\keyword{if}}}
\newcommand{\mfi}{\bb{\keyword{fi}}}
\newcommand{\mthen}{\keyword{\textrightarrow}}

\newcommand\bb[1]
  {{\color{red}\fboxrule=.1pt\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\fbox{\color{black}#1}}}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{\testAUX{\bb{#1}}}
\newcommand\testAUX[1]{%
  {\setlength{\tabbingsep}{0pt}\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
    \begin{tabbing}
      q1, q2, q3, q4 \(≔\) Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4;\\
      \mdoloop\=\ \=q1 \textgreater\ q2 \=\kill
      \mdoloop\>\>q1 \textgreater\ q2\>\mthen\ q1, q2 \(≔\) q2, q1\\
      \>#1\'\>q2 \textgreater\ q3\>\mthen\ q2, q3 \(≔\) q3, q2\\
      \>#1\'\>q3 \textgreater\ q4\>\mthen\ q3, q4 \(≔\) q4, q3\\
      \modloop;\\
      k \(≔\) 0; j \(≔\) 1;\\
      \mdoloop\ j \(\neq\) n \mthen\ \=\mif\=\ \=f(j) \(\le\) f(k)\ \=\kill
      \mdoloop\ j \(\neq\) n \mthen\ \>\mif\>\ \>f(j) \(\le\) f(k)\ \>\mthen\ j \(≔\) j + 1\\
      \>\>#1\'\>f(j) \(\ge\) f(k)\ \>\mthen\ k \(≔\) j; j \(≔\) j + 1\\
      \>\mfi\\
      \modloop\qquad.
  \end{tabbing}}%
}%

\begin{document}
\noindent
Dijkstra choice:
\test{\(⫾\)}
\noindent
Dijkstra choice in display style:
\test{\(\displaystyle ⫾\)}
\noindent
n-ary Dijkstra choice:
\test{\(⫿\)}
\noindent
n-ary Dijkstra choice in display style:
\test{\(\displaystyle ⫿\)}
\end{document}


The easiest remedy for this is to use a small negative kern around your symbol to make the bounding box tighter. As a proof of concept the following defines auxiliary macros which wrap the two symbols in negative kerns. Of course to get perfect alignment you'd have to also consider the bigger (and most importantly not equally bigger) bounding boxes around do, od, if, and fi and will need to use different values in different places.
\documentclass[border=3.14,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont[Extension=.otf,range={"2AFE,"2AFF}]{STIXTwoMath-Regular}% more modern
\setmathfont[range={}]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\newcommand{\keyword}[1]{\textsf{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\mdoloop}{\bb{\keyword{do}}}
\newcommand{\modloop}{\bb{\keyword{od}}}
\newcommand{\mif}{\bb{\keyword{if}}}
\newcommand{\mfi}{\bb{\keyword{fi}}}
\newcommand{\mthen}{\keyword{\textrightarrow}}

\newcommand\DijkstraChoice{\kern-.065em⫾\kern-.065em}
\newcommand\naryDijkstraChoice{\kern-.065em⫿\kern-.065em}

\newcommand\bb[1]
  {{\color{red}\fboxrule=.1pt\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\fbox{\color{black}#1}}}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{\testAUX{\bb{#1}}}
\newcommand\testAUX[1]{%
  {\setlength{\tabbingsep}{0pt}\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
    \begin{tabbing}
      q1, q2, q3, q4 \(≔\) Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4;\\
      \mdoloop\=\ \=q1 \textgreater\ q2 \=\kill
      \mdoloop\>\>q1 \textgreater\ q2\>\mthen\ q1, q2 \(≔\) q2, q1\\
      \>#1\'\>q2 \textgreater\ q3\>\mthen\ q2, q3 \(≔\) q3, q2\\
      \>#1\'\>q3 \textgreater\ q4\>\mthen\ q3, q4 \(≔\) q4, q3\\
      \modloop;\\
      k \(≔\) 0; j \(≔\) 1;\\
      \mdoloop\ j \(\neq\) n \mthen\ \=\mif\=\ \=f(j) \(\le\) f(k)\ \=\kill
      \mdoloop\ j \(\neq\) n \mthen\ \>\mif\>\ \>f(j) \(\le\) f(k)\ \>\mthen\ j \(≔\) j + 1\\
      \>\>#1\'\>f(j) \(\ge\) f(k)\ \>\mthen\ k \(≔\) j; j \(≔\) j + 1\\
      \>\mfi\\
      \modloop\qquad.
  \end{tabbing}}%
}%

\begin{document}
\noindent
Dijkstra choice:
\test{\(\DijkstraChoice\)}
\noindent
Dijkstra choice in display style:
\test{\(\displaystyle \DijkstraChoice\)}
\noindent
n-ary Dijkstra choice:
\test{\(\naryDijkstraChoice\)}
\noindent
n-ary Dijkstra choice in display style:
\test{\(\displaystyle \naryDijkstraChoice\)}
\end{document}


